# EDAS Paper Submission warning

Tags: ieeeconf

I have written a research paper and I am targeting to submit it to one of the IEEE Conference, recently I got one such and I have submitted my manuscript to EDAS for review.

After Submission, I got this warning which states that there is some printing issue but I could not able figure out what it is and how to resolve it.

The **warning** is:

PDF check internal problem (100): Network is down Invalid activation If you have not yet received an activation code for your license code please use the following command to request it: *** pdfToolbox -k "your name" "company name" [ | | trial | trialaddon ] *** For requesting a trial license please enter the word "trial" as the license code For requesting a trial dispatcher license please enter the word "trialdispatcher" as the license code For requesting an additional DeviceLink AddOn trial license enter the word "trialaddon" as the license code Follow the instructions to obtain your activation. In case you have received an Activation PDF use the following command: *** pdfToolbox --activate Error 1008    Not activated (no license)

Help would highly be appreciated.

Comment: it says network is down. how is it related to TeX?